# Typeerror : a bytes-like object is required ,not 'str'-python 3.6 for the code

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make client that sends string ( 'hello') but there is that error
for tcp client :

```
    from socket import* 
    servername ='localhost'
    serverport=12000
     while(1):    
         clientsocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)     
         clientsocket.connect((servername,serverport))     
         sentence=input("Input sentence:")     
         clientsocket.send(sentence)     
         ModifiedSentence = clientsocket.recv(1024)     
         print ('From Server:', ModifiedSentence)     
         clientsocket.close()
```

Comment: Please add the full error, which line is causing it? In python3 strings are unicode objects and byte objects are written with a b in front of the string: `b'foo'`. If you have a string and need a byte object, you need to encode it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): 
 file "<stdin>",line 6 , in <module> 
typeError: a bytes-like object is required , not 'str'